What's the name of the TV series with an Army guy who can control electronic devices signals with his mind?
I was wandering about the name of the series where a guy in the Army controls Electronic devices signals with his brain (sort of like talking to them).
It was so cool, like he can tell a mobile phone to make a call even without touching it.
Does anyone remember this tv series??

The power is referred to as 'technopathy,' a subset of technological manipulation. I don't remember a show where a fellow in the Army does it, but if it exists it would be listed here: http://powerlisting.wikia.com/wiki/Technology_Manipulation -- one of the best examples of this power showing up on a TV show is the character Micah in Heroes

You might be thinking of Jake 2.0, in which the hero develops the power to manipulate technology with his mind after being infected by nanobots.  However, he works for the National Security Agency, not the army.

Thanks a lot @FredH, but it seems discontinued though (bummer)
